# 9.4.2: Function definition: Volume of a pyramid with modular functions

Tags: python

I'm not sure where I'm off at, here is the ask.
Define a function `calc_pyramid_volume()` with parameters `base_length`, `base_width`, and `pyramid_height`, that returns the volume of a pyramid with a rectangular base. `calc_pyramid_volume()` calls the given `calc_base_area()` function in the calculation.

Relevant geometry equations:

```
Volume = base area x height x 1/3
(Watch out for integer division).

Sample output with inputs: 4.5 2.1 3.0
Volume for 4.5, 2.1, 3.0 is: 9.45
```

Naturally, my code is not working.

```
def calc_base_area(base_length, base_width):
    return base_length * base_width
    
def calc_pyramid_volume(base_area, pyramid_heigth):
    return calc_base_area * pyramid_heigth 
    
length = float(input())
width = float(input())
height = float(input())
print('Volume for', length, width, height, "is:", calc_pyramid_volume(length, width, height))
```

Comment: `calc_base_area` is a function, and you try to multiply that function object with `pyramid_height`, that wont work. You want to *use* the `calc_base_area`, with appropriate arguments, and multiply the *result of that*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not working because, inside the `calc_pyramid_volume` you've only referenced the function `calc_base_area` but not called it with the relative arguments, so all you have to do is to call it with the `base_length` and `base_width` arguments and return a third of the result, like this...

```py
def calc_base_area(base_length, base_width):
    return base_length * base_width

def calc_pyramid_volume(base_length, base_width, pyramid_height):
    return (calc_base_area(base_length, base_width) * pyramid_height)/3

length = float(input())
width = float(input())
height = float(input())
print('Volume for', length, width, height, "is :", calc_pyramid_volume(length, width, height))
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a simpler solution:

```
def pyramid_volume(length, width, height):
        return (length * width) * height/3
        
    length = float(input())
    width = float(input())
    height = float(input())
    print('Volume for', length, width, height, "is:", pyramid_volume(length, width, height)
```

I'm pretty new to this so I'm just hoping this might help.

Comment: OP specifically asked for a solution with two modular functions.

Answer (score 0):

You must first calculate the area of the base:

```
def calc_base_area(base_length, base_width):
    return base_length * base_width
    
def calc_pyramid_volume(base_area, pyramid_heigth):
    return calc_base_area * pyramid_heigth 
    
length = float(input())
width = float(input())
height = float(input())
base = calc_base_area(length, width)
print('Volume for', length, width, height, "is:", calc_pyramid_volume(base, height))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked for me is: (It is slightly modified from the other one to work with the most recent Zybooks version)

```
def base_area(base_length, base_width):
    return base_length * base_width

def pyramid_volume(base_length, base_width, pyramid_height):
    return (base_area(base_length, base_width) * pyramid_height)/3

length = float(input())
width = float(input())
height = float(input())
print('Volume for 4.5, 2.1, 3.0 is:', pyramid_volume(length, width, height))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me.

def calc_pyramid_volume(base_length, base_width, pyramid_height):

```
base_area = base_length * base_width

volume = (base_area * pyramid_height) / 3

return (base_length * base_width) * pyramid_height / 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calc_base_area(base_length, base_width):
   return base_length * base_width
def calc_pyramid_volume(base_length,base_width,pyramid_height):
    return (length*width) * height * 1/3
length = float(input())
width = float(input())
height = float(input())
print('Volume for', length, width, height, "is:", calc_pyramid_volume(length, width, height))
```

You do not need to include the `calc_base_area` function since you can just solve that in the `calc_pyramid_volume` function. Still should work as an answer in Zybooks though.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the answer that worked for me when solving it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvOho.png)

I did:

```
def calc_pyramid_volume(base_length, base_width, pyramid_height):

area = length * width

volume = area * height * 1/3

return volume
```

and it worked perfectly for me.